# Java allocating more RAM when lots is already free

Tags: java, garbage-collection, arguments, server, ram

Please note: This is for a Minecraft server.

In Java, what options can I specify to make Java not allocate RAM *until all free RAM is filled?*

Here is a picture of my RAM usage currently:

```
Allocated Memory: 1458MB
Free Memory: 514MB
Totaly Memory: 4062MB
```

Task Manager says Java is using 1458MBs of RAM, which is the problem. The server is only using 944MBs (1458-514) and I want a way to keep memory usage as low as possible, until that space is filled.

Current arguments: `-server -Xincgc -Xms512M -Xmx4096M -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+AggressiveOpts -jar cauldron.jar nogui`

Comment: Why do you care? RAM is there to be used...

Comment: If you're worried about the total memory allocation, can't you just reduce -Xmx?

Comment: You really don't want that, because it will bring the server performance to a standstill. While all of that memory isn't necessarily being used at once, the JVM is constantly creating and destroying objects and then moving them around to make room for new ones. Not having spare heap space will make your program constantly wait on the garbage collector instead of letting the JVM do garbage collection more concurrently.

Comment: Ok, if you say so. The reason I wanted it is to have multiple instances on the same host. With a smaller amount of memory usage comes fewer machines.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `-Xmx4096M` argument, which allows the JVM to allocate up to 4096MB of memory.
If you would like to reduce this memory usage in your system, you should reduce this value.

From the [java tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) documentation:

> -Xmxsize
>
> Specifies the maximum size (in bytes) of the memory allocation pool in bytes. This value must be a multiple of 1024 and greater than 2 MB. Append the letter k or K to indicate kilobytes, m or M to indicate megabytes, g or G to indicate gigabytes. The default value is chosen at runtime based on system configuration.
>
> The -Xmx option is equivalent to -XX:MaxHeapSize.

Comment: My system has 8GBs of memory. When 8 or so people are on the server, the RAM usage goes up to 4GBs, the max allowed. In that respect everything works fine. I just want the RAM to clock down and use as little as possible when only a few people (or nobody) is on.